# Restrict the build installing in the 10" Tab

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I have added the following lines to the `manifest.xml` and still i could install the .apk in the 10" devices . I want the .apk file to be installed only in the 7" tablet .

```
<supports-screens
         android:smallScreens="false"
         android:normalScreens="false"
         android:largeScreens="true"
         android:xlargeScreens="false"
         android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
         android:largestWidthLimitDp="700"/>

    <compatible-screens>
        <!--no small size screens -->
        <!--no normal size screens -->
        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- no xlarge size screens -->

</compatible-screens>
```

I don't know where i am going wrong . Thanks in advance .

Comment: How did you checked it?? Did you uploaded the .apk file to play store and checked??

Comment: No i just run the app through eclipse IDE , directly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<supports-screen>` and `<compatible-screens>` only affects Google Play Store downloading (i.e., devices not compatible will not show up as install targets). However, sideloading the APK gets around any Google Play compatibility filtering (as Google Play is not involved).

Comment: @VIGNESH - the one thing I see missing is a tvdpi entry for `<compatible-screens>` (for supporting devices such as the 2012 Nexus 7):
`<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />`